# Dark Mode in Outlook.com

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I'm wondering if I can change the dark mode colours in Outlook.com because it looks gross. [On mac it looks exactly like I want it. Windows it simply inverts colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84nEX.png)
Is there any method how can I change darkmode properties specifically to clients and OS?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is quite a beast when it comes to dark mode because you'll find many variations.

- Outlook on macOS has good supports for `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark)` media queries, so you should have full control there.
- Outlook on iOS, Android and Outlook.com on the web also have support for `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark)`. But it also applies automatic color changes on top of this. You can try to tweak this using `[data-ogsb]` attribute selectors to target the matching elements.
- Outlook on Windows applies automatic color changes and supports neither the dark mode media query nor data attributes. You can try to play with VML and `mso-` specific properties though.

I would recommend reading the following articles:

- [The Ultimate Guide to Dark Mode for Email Marketers](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/) by Alice Li
- [How To Fix Outlook Dark Mode Problems](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-outlook-dark-mode-problems--cms-37718) by Nicole Merlin
- [Making Emails React to Outlook.com’s Dark Mode](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/emails-react-outlook-com-dark-mode/)  by me!

Feel free to post your code for more specific help.